# What kind of parameter unpacking is "... ..."?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I had a look at the source of `<functional>` in libstdc++ (g++ 4.7.1) and found the following code ([l. 91 - 98](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/libstdc++/api/a01173_source.html#l00080)):

```
/// Retrieve the result type for a function type.
template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
struct _Weak_result_type_impl<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>    // (1)
{ typedef _Res result_type; };

template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
struct _Weak_result_type_impl<_Res(_ArgTypes......)> // (2) line 97
{ typedef _Res result_type; };
```

While I recognize the usual pack expansion `...` (1) [temp.variadic], I have no idea what `......` is.

What does `......` (2) mean in this context?

#### Follow-up question

In the following [minimal example](http://ideone.com/YlEEz3), what type would I need for `TEST_PARAM_3` such that `tester<TEST_PARAM_3>::value == 2`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename Functor>
struct tester : std::integral_constant<int, 0>{};

template <typename Res, typename... Args>
struct tester<Res(Args...)> : std::integral_constant<int, 1>{};

template <typename Res, typename... Args>
struct tester<Res(Args......)> : std::integral_constant<int, 2>{};

#define STR_EXPAND(tok) #tok
#define STR(tok) STR_EXPAND(tok)
#define TEST_PARAM_1 void(*)(int, int)
#define TEST_PARAM_2 void(int, char, std::ostream&)
#define TEST_PARAM_3 void()

int main(){
    using std::setw;
    std::cout
    << setw(65)<< STR(TEST_PARAM_1) ": " << tester<TEST_PARAM_1>::value << "\n"
    << setw(65)<< STR(TEST_PARAM_2) ": " << tester<TEST_PARAM_2>::value << "\n"
    << setw(65)<< STR(TEST_PARAM_3) ": " << tester<TEST_PARAM_3>::value << "\n";
}
```

Comment: [C11 variadic template arguments](http://lbrandy.com/blog/2013/02/c11s-six-dots/)

Comment: For your follow-up question: [`void(...)`](http://ideone.com/vU1ZSa)

Comment: @Yuushi: Indeed. `......` doesn't seem to play well with the search function and search engines.

Comment: @Zeta I just searched for `C++ "six dots"` in Google and it worked :P

Comment: @Zeta To be fair, it is definitely one of the stranger corners of C++. I stumbled upon that answer not too long ago, so it was relatively fresh in my memory...

Comment: @Yuushi But not so strange anymore if you consider `_ArgTypes...` as a "single" type, like `int`, then you can read `_Res(int...)` which reminds of a certain "`printf`" signature... (But yes, they could have inserted a space between the two `...` for readability...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the last `...` is actually equivalent to `, ...`.

Which makes the template parameter:

```
Res(Args..., ...)
```

Which means this is a [variadic function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic), with a template variadic number of fixed arguments.